Xcode 16 beta & share extension
Not sure if this is an Xcode issue, an iOS device issue or MacOS issue. Seems writing a basic share extension app in Swift, does not allow me to deploy the extension target app to my device (although it will deploy on an iOS 18 simulator). The error reads “The specified capability is not supported by this device.”  Has anyone seen this before and have thoughts on how to address it?  Thanks!
I’ve tried re-installing Xcode 16 beta. I’ve tried it on another iPhone and another Mac, yet the same error occurs.
